# Creating a data structure without duplicating keys

Tags: ruby, data-structures

I have multiple classes that have the following two hash tables. Both mappings must have an identical set of keys. My problem is that there are many classes with this structure and that the key sets will change over time.

```
mapping_1 = {
  :key_1 => "attr_1_1",
  :key_2 => "attr_2_1",
  :key_3 => "attr_3_1"
}

mapping_2 = {
  :key_1 => "attr_1_2",
  :key_2 => "attr_2_2",
  :key_3 => "attr_3_2"
}
```

I need to be able to access the values given the keys for both mappings and the key from the value with mapping 1. In other words, I need to be able to perform these operations:

```
mapping_1[:key_1]
mapping_1.index("attr_2_1")  #(Ruby 1.8.7)
mapping_2[:key_3]
```

**Question:** Is there a way where I wouldn't have to duplicate writing the keys in both structures?

I thought of having the key map to an array( `:key_1 => ["attr_1_1", "attr_1_2"]` ) but this won't work because when I run the command `mapping_1.index()` I don't know what the value of the second attribute is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should definitely create your own hash class and use it instead of `Hash`. It would take care of the keyset, and wrap per-object storage.

It could have class methods to edit your keyset such as:

```
def self.add_key(key, default_value)
def self.remove_key(key)
```

and instance methods that you would use in your container classes, which would mimick `Hash` methods:

```
def get(key)
def set(key, value)
def find_key(value)
```

etc. You could use ordinary `Hash` for underlying storage, of course. If you need to be able to expand your keyset whenever you add a new key to any of the instances, just call `add_key` from `set`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a multidimensional array like my `a` below.  Ruby's array methods will allow for you to do what you need.  I used `find_all`, and there is probably even something more direct.

```
irb(main):049:0> a
=> {"key1"=>["attr1_a", "attr1_b"], "key2"=>["attr2_a", "attr2_b"]}
irb(main):050:0> a['key2']
=> ["attr2_a", "attr2_b"]
irb(main):051:0> a.keys
=> ["key1", "key2"]
irb(main):052:0> a.keys.find_all{|k| a[k].include?('attr2_b')}
=> ["key2"]
```

Of course, if you made your own class like other poster suggested you could create a method to do the search in some like `a.key_containing('attr2_b')` instead of the somewhat-messy `find_all` string above

Answer (score 1):

Try out Multimap: https://github.com/josh/multimap. It allows to have multiple values per key and have index operation. See here, for example: https://github.com/josh/multimap/blob/master/lib/multimap.rb.

```
  # call-seq:
  #   map.index(value)    => key
  #
  # Returns the key for a given value. If not found, returns
  # <tt>nil</tt>.
  #
  #   map = Multimap["a" => 100, "b" => [200, 300]]
  #   map.index(100)   #=> "a"
  #   map.index(200)   #=> "b"
  #   map.index(999)   #=> nil
  def index(value)
    invert[value]
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
SET_OF_KEYS = [:key_1, :key_2, :key_3]

Mapping = Struct.new( *SET_OF_KEYS )
class Mapping
  def index(value)
    kv = self.each_pair.detect{|k,v| v == value }
    kv.nil? ? nil : kv.first
  end
end 

mapping_1 = Mapping.new("attr_1_1", "attr_2_1", "attr_3_1")
mapping_2 = Mapping.new("attr_1_2", "attr_2_2", "attr_3_2")

p mapping_1[:key_1]  #=> "attr_1_1"
p mapping_1.index("attr_2_1")  #=> :key_2
p mapping_2[:key_3]  #=>  "attr_3_2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a module and include it in the relevant classes.

```
module MapHandeling
    def [] key; @map ||= {}; @map[key] end
    def []= key, value; @map ||= {}; @map[key] = value end
    def index key; @map ||= {}; @map.index(key) end
end
```

or

```
module MapHandeling
    def initialize map; @map = map end
    def [] key; @map[key] end
    def []= key, value; @map[key] = value end
    def index key; @map.index(key) end
end
```

> class A; include MapHandeling end

```
a = A.new(some_hash)
a[:key1] = :attr1
a[:key1] #=> :attr1
a.index(:attr1) = :key1
```